# converting an ajax request to angular $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm learning how to use angular and I'm not really that familiar with making request to an api. I'm trying to practice using http://api.football-data.org/index. The json data I wanted to get from my angular factory is http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable. Right now I'm getting an error in the console

> 'angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLeagueData' of undefined at new ...'

My CLI shows that I am loading all my script files and I tested my controller before trying to bring in the factory and creating the getLeagueData function and it was working so I know my issue is after creating the basic controller. I thought it might have to do with my headers needing the authentification token I received but I'm not sure if I haven't added it correctly. Here is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='bplApp'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title><%= title %></title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--Custom-->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/main.css'>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class='leagueCheck' ng-controller='tableController as table'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'>
        {{table.test}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<!--Module-->
<script src='bplApp.js'></script>
<!--Controller-->
<script src='/controllers/tableController.js'></script>
<!--Service-->
<script src='/services/footballData.js'></script>
```

Module

```
var app = angular.module('bplApp',[]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('tableController', ['$scope', 'footballData', function($scope, footballData){
var self = this;

self.test = 'is working';
self.leagueStats = [];

footballData.getLeagueData().then(function(data){
    self.leagueStats = data;
    console.log(self.leagueStats);
  })
}])
```

Factory

```
app.factory('footballData', [function($http){
      return {
        getLeagueData: function(){
            return $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
              headers:{
                  'X-Auth-Token': '3e629af30fce46edaa6ead20e007a276'
              }
            })
        }  
      }
}])
```

The original ajax code sample that the api shows for using it looks like this

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' },
  url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures?timeFrame=n1',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
}).done(function(response) {
  // do something with the response, e.g. isolate the id of a linked     resource        
  var regex = /.*?(\d+)$/; // the ? makes the first part non-greedy
  var res = regex.exec(response.fixtures[0]._links.awayTeam.href);
  var teamId = res[1];
  console.log(teamId);
});
```

Comment: You haven't injected your `footballData` factory correctly. Change `['$scope', function($scope, footballData)` to `['$scope', 'footballData', function($scope, footballData)`

Comment: Also, don't use the deprecated `success` callback. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. +1 on writing a good question with all the required information though.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the response. I did make your changes and see how both of those were wrong. But it didn't change the response I'm getting from the console about the Object.getLeagueData not being a function

Comment: Actually I guess the error is a different error 
angular.js:13920TypeError: $http is not a function
    at Object.getLeagueData

Comment: Your array annotation is wrong, change it to `app.factory('footballData', [ "$http", function($http){...]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the array notation at your factory. Either use it directly or declare the $http in the array:

```
app.factory('footballData', ["$http", function($http){
      return {
        getLeagueData: function(){
            return $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
              headers:{
                  'X-Auth-Token': '3e629af30fce46edaa6ead20e007a276'
              }
            })
        }  
      }
}])
```

OR

```
app.factory('footballData', function($http){
      return {
        getLeagueData: function(){
            return $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
              headers:{
                  'X-Auth-Token': '3e629af30fce46edaa6ead20e007a276'
              }
            })
        }  
      }
})
```

Which approach to choose is up to you, there is [some docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to assist you on your decision.

Comment: Thank you. I constantly forget that in the array notation. I'm going to have to start writing it the other way.